# Behaviour of Equality and Nested Structures

Tags: python

At some point I got in set in my head that an equality statement against two deeply nested structures is not reliable. It it ever the case that some *deep nest* is ignored when doing a equality check on the outermost container?

I should be clear in stating that by deeply nested structure I mean:

1. Containing only dict, list, built in types and objects I know to compare like datetime.
2. List order is important
3. The container size can be very deep or very wide
4. No generators or custom iterators
5. There is no recursive parts to the nesting

I've done a number of tests and I always get the answer I expect. But, It's nearly impossible to consider the tests I can't think of :)

Comment: Given the constraints you've listed, I think it is reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior for builtin container types is defined [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html).  It says:

> Tuples and lists are compared lexicographically using comparison of corresponding elements. This means that to compare equal, each element must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and have the same length.
>
> Mappings (dictionaries) compare equal if and only if their sorted (key, value) lists compare equal.

So the fact that equality comparisons recurse down to contents is part of the language definition.  It will always check all nested structures that need to be checked.  (This doesn't mean it will always check them all; it may stop when it knows the answer.  For instance, if you test for equality on two deeply nested lists whose first elements are unequal, it will just return False as soon as it notices that one unequal element, without checking the rest of the nested structure.)

Comment: Thanks bren, this was driving me crazy for years. Somebody told me it wasn't reliable... what the context was I don't remember.